# C# equivalent to db.repairDatabase()

Tags: c#, mongodb

Is there a way to call MongoDB's db.repairDatabase() function from the C# driver?

I am able to compact collections:

```
database.RunCommand(new CommandDocument("compact","collectionname"));
```

But I don't manage to call repairDatabase.

Comment: Can you please add the server and driver versions to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comment that you got an exception with the message "bad option", it turns out that the server is picky about whether you use 1 or true as the value for the repairDatabase field. The following two are equivalent and both fail because the server doesn't like "true" instead of "1":

```
database.RunCommand("repairDatabase");
database.RunCommnad(new CommandDocument("repairDatabase", true));
```

but this works:

```
database.RunCommnad(new CommandDocument("repairDatabase", 1));
```

You could report a JIRA against the server if this concerns you:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER

Answer (score 1):

The `database.RunCommand` method is overloaded. It can also take a string that is the name of command, as follows:

```
database.RunCommand("repairDatabase")
```

It also returns a `CommandResult` object.

Comment: I tried that and get the following exception: Command 'repairDatabase' failed: bad option (response: { "errmsg" : "bad option", "ok" : 0.0 })